# Screen recording: windows apps with a delay option?

Tags: screen-recorder

I'm looking for a windows app for recording screen to GIF, similar to [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek). There are tons of screen recording apps, but none of them seem to have a **built-in delay**. Unfortunately this is a feature I'm really looking for. Here's how Peek works: [http://i.imgur.com/qLhiw12.gif](https://i.imgur.com/qLhiw12.gif)

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 with Service Pack 2 (SP2)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=27870) has such a feature. You can install it without any registration code, just press continue when the code is asked for. It delays by 3 seconds.

[image: 3 seconds countdown]
[image: Microsoft Expression Encoder 4 Screen Capture SP2 UI]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really looking for something much simpler. I want to quickly launch the app, press record, and save the gif

Comment: Even easier? Tell me if you find something that is even easier. I consider this app easy to use. Good luck searching.